# Counting the states of an interconnected probability problem

Tags: probability

I’m trying to count possible states for a specific problem, which I have simplified to this:

Suppose we have three people: Judy, Dan and Bella. The three of them stand next to each other in this very same order, and that can’t be changed.
Each one of them can either stand or sit. Those are the only two states for them. I figure this would mean we have 2*2*2=8 states in total for now.
Here is the tricky part. If and only if two of two neighbors of this ensemble are sitting down, they might or might not hold hands. When they stand up there is zero possibility for that happening, the holding hands can only occur when the two neighbors are both sitting down ( so it can only happen between Judy and Dan, or Dan and Bella).
I have difficulty coming up with the right formula for the total number of possible states for this problem.
I need to generalize this to more people (actually, my main system has 7 people and 6 interfaces).

Comment: For clarification, supposing that all three are sitting, can Dan simultaneously hold hands with Judy *and* Bella?  The problem is considerably easier if he is allowed to hold hands with only one of them at a time.  (*Consider recursive sequences and tilings using black 1x1 squares (sitting no handholding), red 1x1 squares (standing), and black 2x1 squares (sitting with handholding))

Comment: @JMoravitz  Yes Dan can do that simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ people in a row. You want $x_1+x_2+2x_3 = n$ where $x_1$ is the number of people standing, $x_2$ is the number of people sitting, and $x_3$ is the number of "couples" holding hands. For each solution to this Diophantine Equation, you want the number of multiset permutations of $\{x_1\cdot S, x_2\cdot s, x_3\cdot H\}$ where $S$ represents a person Standing, $s$ represents a person sitting, and $H$ represents two people sitting and holding hands.

So, the number of states is given by:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{\begin{matrix}\forall i, x_i \in \mathbb{Z} \\ \forall i, 0\le x_i \\ x_1+x_2+2x_3=n\end{matrix}}\dfrac{(x_1+x_2+x_3)!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!}$$

This is @JMoravitz's solution where a person can hold hands with at most one other person at a time.

Maybe give more details on the "6 interfaces"?

Edit: If you want to include the possibility of chains of people all holding hands, then we have $S$ to represent a person standing and $H_i$ for a chain of $i$ people sitting and holding hands. Then you want solutions to the Diophantine equation:

$$x_0+\sum_{i=1}^n ix_i = n$$

Let $\displaystyle A = \left\{(x_0,\ldots, x_n) \in (\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0})^{n+1}: x_0+\sum_{i=1}^n ix_i = n\right\}$, then the number of states is given by:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{(x_0,\ldots, x_n) \in A} \dfrac{\displaystyle \left( \sum_{i=0}^n x_i \right) !}{\displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^n(x_i)!}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe my example is not such a good explanation of the phenomenon I’m trying to understand. I am studying a protein with 7 domains and each domain can be either in a fully folded state or an unfolded state ( which is not the case in nature, but we assume them to be complementary to each other). Now these domains have “interfaces “. We can only say two domains are “coupled” if and only if both domains are fully folded. And that’s what I was going for with the holding hands analogy. Also, I don’t know the number of standing or sitting people, basically I am just trying

Comment: To come up with how many possible states could this system have. A bunch of people, either standing or sitting, and a possibility of them holding hands. How many possible ways are there in this system?

Comment: Then my first formula is correct. You can calculate the number of states with a program. Have $x_3$ go from 0 to 3, have $x_2$ go from 0 to $7-2x_3$, and have $x_1 = 7-2x_3-x_2$. That is your loop, and you keep adding $\dfrac{(x_1+x_2+x_3)!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!}$

Comment: Ok I tried it and it gives a really huge number, and I don't think my code is wrong. I used the loop in the order as you said above. I know this order does not work for at least x2 from 0 to 3, because I counted that by hand and it was 13 states in total.

Comment: I got 408 states.

Comment: Ok, I just got it, Thanks! Although it doesn't make physical sense. I'll look more in to it.

Comment: Ignoring the "coupled" states, there are $2^7 = 128$ states. Now, suppose the leftmost pair is a "couple". Ignoring coupled states, there are $2^5=32$ different states for the remaining 5 people. You can move the couple to the right one and there are another $2^5$ different states for the remaining 5 people. Etc. So, that is a total of $6\cdot 32 = 192$ different states more (each with exactly one couple).

Next, what if there are exactly two couples? Then exactly three couples? This is what my formula was counting.

Comment: Above, you said that Dan could hold hands with both adjacent people simultaneously. If that is the case, then the total number of states is 610 (with 7 people).

Comment: How would that go?

Comment: That uses the formula at the bottom of my post. Let $x_7$ go from 0 to 1, $x_6$ from 0 to $\lfloor (7-7x_7)/5 \rfloor $,  $x_5$ from 0 to $\lfloor (7-7x_7-6x_6)/5\rfloor $, $x_4$ from 0 to $\lfloor ( 7-7x_7-6x_6-5x_5)/4 \rfloor $, $x_3$ from 0 to $\lfloor (7-7x_7-6x_6-5x_5-4x_4)/3 \rfloor $, $x_2$ from 0 to $\lfloor (7-7x_7-6x_6-5x_5-4x_4-3x_3)/2 \rfloor $, $x_1$ from 0 to $7-7x_7-6x_6-5x_5-4x_4-3x_3-2x_2$ and $x_0$ from 0 to $7-7x_7-6x_6-5x_5-4x_4-3x_3-2x_2-x_1$

Comment: Oops, $x_0$ is not a variable. It is always the upper bound I set in my comment above.

Comment: I dont understand why when we extend the array, we are thinking of more xi. What are the x1, ....x7 representing? and why are they multiplied by their own index?

Comment: Dan holding hands with both Judy and Bella is three people in a row that are all holding hands. It is not a multiple of 2. Judy + Dan is an overlapping couple with Dan + Bella. The multiplication by its own index represents the number of people in a line all holding hands. So, 
$$x_0+\sum_{i=1}^7 ix_i = 7$$

represents $x_0$ people standing, $x_1$ people sitting (you can say holding hands with themself).
$x_2$ couples holding hands (taking up 2 people),
$x_3$ chains of 3 people all holding hands... 
$x_7$ chains of 7 people all holding hands

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.